# Description of irreducible closed subsets of $\mathbb A^m_k \times \mathbb A^n_k$

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology, affine-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and for positive integer $n$, consider the affine $n$-space $\mathbb A^n_k$ with Zariski topology. Consider $\mathbb A^m_k \times \mathbb A^n_k$ with product topology. Is there a good description of the irreducible closed subsets of the topological space $\mathbb A^m_k \times \mathbb A^n_k$ (possibly in terms of irreducible closed subsets of $\mathbb A^m_k, \mathbb A^n_k$) ?

I know that for irreducible subsets $X,Y$ of $\mathbb A^m_k, \mathbb A^n_k$ respectively, $X\times Y$ is irreducible in $\mathbb A^m_k \times \mathbb A^n_k$, but I don't know whether these are all irreducible closed subsets of  $\mathbb A^m_k \times \mathbb A^n_k$ or not ...

Comment: I feel that the moment you say it's the product topology this has nothing to do with affine space. You could ask the same question for any spaces $X$ and $Y$ and the answer will be the same.

Comment: @user347489: ok .... so what is the answer then ?